# spectrum of unbounded self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I'm self-studying Lax's functional analysis, and I'm stuck in the chapter introducing spectral theory for unbounded self-adjoint operators.

In his book, Lax proved the spectral theorem of this version in p.378 using Nevanlinna's lemma, or Tao called Herglotz representation theorem :

> Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space $H$; denote the domain of $A$ by $D$. There is a spectral resolution for $A$, that is, orthogonal projection-valued measure $E$ defined for all Borel measurable subsets of $R$, with the following properties:

- $E(\emptyset)=0, E(\mathbb{R})=1$
- $E(S\cap T)=E(S)E(T)$
- $E^*=E$
- $E$ commutes with $A$
- $D=\left\{u\in H \mid \int t^2dE(t)u<\infty \right\}$

I'm fairly well following the proof given in this book, but I found out several points I cannot make clear about. My question is:

1. It seems to me that Lax does not completely prove the theorem; at the final step he just showed $D\subseteq \left\{u\in H \mid \int t^2dE(t)u<\infty \right\}$. But some cross validation, like [Tao's post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/the-spectral-theorem-and-its-converses-for-unbounded-symmetric-operators/), says inverse direction is also true, and I cannot fill in the missing proof for myself.
2. In p.390 in Lax, he give an exercise showing unbounded self-adjoint operator has closed unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ as the spectrum. I succeed in showing that the spectrum is a closed subset of the real line(it seems to be exactly the same as in bounded case), but failed to show the unboundedness.

Any hint or reference would be really appreciated.

---

I've came up with an idea about 2nd question that if $\sigma(A)$ is bounded, say $|\sigma(A)|<M$, then $A=\int_{\sigma(A)} tdE(t)$ has bounded norm $|A|<\int_{-M}^M |t|dt=M^2$, which is contradiction. Is my argument make sense?

Comment: (by definition ?) an unbounded operator has a sequence of singular values which tend $\to \infty$. and the singular values of a self-adjoint operators are the same as its eigenvalues

Comment: @user1952009 : Sorry I'm newbie in this stuff, why unbounded operator has divergent seq of singular values?

Comment: I'm not sure of the proof, but every bounded operator has a SVD, hence intuitively any unbounded operator too, and its singular values are then unbounded (otherwise the operator would be bounded).

Comment: @user1952009: The compact operators are precisely the almost finite rank operators, i.e. they admit a SVD. Even bounded selfadjoint operators may have no eigenvalues **at all**.

Comment: @cjackal: Your reasoning is correct but you're still missing: $\sigma A=\operatorname{supp}E$

Comment: @Freeze_S : I think $\sigma (A)=\mathrm{supp}(E)$ is not so hard, considering $A-zI=\int (t-z)dE(t)$.

Comment: Exactly! And so you even get: $\|f(A)\|=\|f\|_{\operatorname{supp}E}$ *(Possibly infinite!)*

Comment: Now for your first question you need a trick: Prove that $f(A)^*=f^*(A)$ and $(fg)(A)=\overline{f(A)g(A)}$. So they are all normal! But normal operators are maximal in the sense if $N\subseteq N'$ then $N=N'$.

Comment: You might have a look into [Spectral Measures](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A79762+title%3A%22Spectral+Measures%22+is%3Aquestion) and [Normal Operators](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A79762+title%3A%22Normal+Operators%22+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: @Freeze_S : Thanks for comments and comprehensive posts, I just realized that $\int f(t)dE(t)$ with domain $\left\{\int |f|^2 d<E(t)v,v><\infty\right\}$ is closed as $f(A)^*=f^*(A)$ and $f(t)=t$ case extends $A$ so taking adjoint and get $A^*=A$ extends $\int tdE(t)$, the desired result. I want to accept your answer but functionally it is not allowed to accept a comment as answer, so how about making simple post here to get some points due to you?

Answer (score 2):

You know that $E(S)x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ for all $x$ if $S$ is a bounded measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. And
$$
      AE(-R,R]x = \int_{-R}^{R}\lambda dE(\lambda)x.
$$
Furthermore,
$$
          \|AE(-R,R]x\|^2 = \int_{-R}^{R}\lambda^2d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2.
$$

If $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$, then $AE(-R,R]x=E(-R,R]Ax$ converges to $Ax$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ and, therefore, the above gives
$$
      x \in\mathcal{D}(A)\implies \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda^2d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 < \infty.   \tag{*}
$$
Conversely, if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda^2 d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 < \infty$, then $AE(-R,R]x=\int_{-R}^{R}\lambda dE(\lambda)x$ converges as $R\rightarrow\infty$ to some $y$. Because $E(-R,R]x\rightarrow x$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, and $AE(-R,R]x\rightarrow y$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$, and because $A$ is closed, then $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ and $Ax=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda dE(\lambda)x$. Hence, the reverse implication is proved for $(*)$, which gives the full characterization of $\mathcal{D}(A)$.

Comment: do you mind explaining why is $E(S)x \in D(A)$? Thank you.

Comment: @user3342072 : You know that $x\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ iff $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lambda^2 d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2 < \infty$. So, $E(S)x$ is in the domain of $A$ if $S$ is bounded, because applying $E(S)$ to $x$ effectively truncates the integral to $\int_{S}\lambda^2 d\|E(\lambda)x\|^2$, which is finite, regardless of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered the question [spectrum of unbounded self-adjoint operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734776/spectrum-of-unbounded-self-adjoint-operators). You can find a proof for your second point in

Weidmann, Joachim. Linear operators in Hilbert spaces. Vol. 68. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

It seems, however, that this book uses a somewhat different concept than Lax - that of a spectral family instead of a spectral resolution. But perhaps you can translate the relevant ideas into Lax's framework.